# entity translation of menu

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

i have set up entity translation and everything is working. except for menus. I have a translation set defined for a menu item in "main-menu" and have 2 languages set up for a menu item. However, now both show up in the main menu regardless of which language i am in.

any clues?

its possible my custom menu tree may have something to do with it?

in page.tpl >

```
$pid = variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu');
$tree = menu_tree($pid);
$tree = str_replace(' class="menu"', '', $tree);
$main_menu = drupal_render($tree);
print $main_menu;
```

Comment: What is a reason that you output menu programmatically? Did you check language detection settings?

Comment: to get the 'menu tree' (main menu with children). wrong way maybe? here is my language detection settings (URL and Session on both in that order) http://i1082.photobucket.com/albums/j364/peterthimaging/Screenshot2013-01-09at90201AM_zps59414f51.png

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with i18n_menu_translated_tree

`$tree = i18n_menu_translated_tree($pid);`

as an alert for the next guy, there is some development to move towards i18n_menu_translated_menu_link_alter()
http://drupal.org/node/1693074

Answer (score 0):

1) Show menu as tree:

just edit each menu link that must be expanded and check `Show as expanded`. Than you can enable your menu block.

2) Menu translation:

Each menu title is translatable via standart Drupal form at `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`